# Transform long format data into compact summary table with multiple values in each cell in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I need to transform a long format table with columns for each summary statistic and rows for each group/visit combination into a compact table with rows for each group and columns for each visit. See photo for example.

[image: Example photo]

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(value = paste0(mean, " ± ", round(SE, 2), " (n = ", n, ")")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Group,
              names_from = Visit,
              names_prefix = "Day_",
              values_from = value)
```

returns

```r
  Group Day_1               Day_2               Day_3              
  <chr> <chr>               <chr>               <chr>              
1 A     27 ± 0.33 (n = 100) 22 ± 0.81 (n = 100) 21 ± 0.79 (n = 100)
2 B     29 ± 0.82 (n = 100) 23 ± 0.93 (n = 100) 20 ± 0.96 (n = 100)
3 C     24 ± 0.37 (n = 100) 26 ± 0.24 (n = 100) 25 ± 0.1 (n = 100)
```

### Data

```
df <- structure(list(Visit = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    Group = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"), mean = c(27L, 
    29L, 24L, 22L, 23L, 26L, 21L, 20L, 25L), SE = c(0.332081410568208, 
    0.818319256883115, 0.371742388699204, 0.809606711380184, 
    0.931074212538078, 0.244411387946457, 0.79078992898576, 0.955696877092123, 
    0.0983989259693772), n = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
    100, 100, 100)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R option might help

```
reshape(
  transform(
    df,
    Day = sprintf("%s±%s(n=%s)", mean, round(SE, 2), n)
  )[c("Visit", "Group", "Day")],
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "Group",
  timevar = "Visit"
)
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) any (not necessarily mine) of the answers if you found them useful.